# What AWS costs can add up fast?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For companies using Amazon Web Services, what are some "hidden" costs or service costs you might not think about that can add up quickly to a monthly bill and lead to sticker shock? What's the best way to make sure that doesn't happen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

There are many AWS services. Without knowing what services you are using, it is difficult to comment on hidden costs. For most accounts, `EC2` compute charges will be > 50% of costs. If you are using `S3` heavily to serve documents, then data transfer cost will be substantial.

If you are worried about sticker shock at the end of the month, you can set up billing alerts so that when your cost exceeds a threshold, you will get an alert immediately.

For more info:

[Creating a Billing Alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-alarms.html)

[Monitoring Charges with Alerts and Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/monitor-charges.html)

[Simple Monthly Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

Comment: Also, many people find that their **Data Transfer** cost is high, but this again depends on whether the application is being used by many Internet users, or whether it is more of a 'back-end' data processing service.

Answer (score 0):

For "not obvious" costs you can refer: [What are hidden costs or "NOT obvious" costs on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396508/what-are-hidden-costs-or-not-obvious-costs-on-aws/45396509#45396509)

Also, costs which can add up fast depends on your application; but in a general application total bill is distributed as follows [just to give you ballpark numbers]:

1. 50% of bill for EC2
2. 30% of bill for RDS [compute + Provisioned IOPS ]
3. 3% of bill for Support
4. Even Redshift is a very expensive service if u use it.
5. 5% Data transfer cost