# What are hidden costs or "NOT obvious" costs on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-aurora

AWS says that everything is "pay as you use". But are there any hidden costs or "NOT obvious" costs on AWS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Costs which generally are ignored by people and can give shock:

1. It is recommended that we deploy our application in Multi AZ for High availability. We assume that data transfer between these servers will be free as this is like intranet; but that is not true. There are charges ( around 10% of internet bandwidth charges ) for data transfer across AZ in same region.
2. Data transfer within AWS and across AWS regions is also charged.
3. On AWS Aurora; by default provisioned IOPS are enabled which leads to a huge bill.
4. If Versioning is enabled on S3; then u need to pay for all versions of every object.

These are not hidden charges but can give you a shock:

1. Even on other RDS; if u use provisioned IOPS it leads to a huge bill depending on usage.

Comment: Traffic between Amazon EC2 instances in different Availability Zones but in the same Region is 1c/GB. There is no charge for Data Transfer "within AWS" within the same region. See: [Amazon EC2 pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)

Comment: I agree John. Did I said anything else !

Comment: I have a couple more. EC2 heavy usage (which happens when you run out of CPU credits on t2 and t3 burstable instances) can turn out to be very expensive, especially if you're often running CPU intensive operations. If you run expensive queries on millions of records on AWS Aurora, expect to receive StorageIOUsage costs as they charge per million requests (each individual row counts as a request). Lastly, AWS NAT Gateway minimum costs you $30 a month.